# Scalene with long running program

Tags: python, profiler, scalene

I know I can run scalene with

```
scalene --cli your_prog.py
```

but for long running program how can I regularly print memory usage? (using gui/cli scalene)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking at all. ¿Do you need to get memory usage status each **x seconds** when you have a program that is running in a big period of time?

Comment: Yes I want to get status every x seconds

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, there is an option

```
--profile-interval PROFILE_INTERVAL
```

to output profile interval every PROFILE_INTERVAL seconds, default is infinity

you can get all these options using

```
scalene --help
```

Comment: Great!! Just to know, what are you using scalene for? Cause thanks your question i started to check it out and it seems an interesting use for monitoring an python app but i saw that it can may be usefull for just monitoring python programs... My question comes cause i use python for data science!

Comment: its helpful for cpu and memory profiling and also can debug memory leaks @mrCatlost